# Why Button is not working in my datalist control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I'm using a datalist control to show product details before adding to cart. But here add to cart button is not working. How can I resolve this problem?
Here is the code of datalist control

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="container" style="z-index:-1;">
                <div class="wrapper" style="margin-left:400px;" >
                    <div class="databox effect1">
                        <div  id="imagedata" style="padding:10px">
                            <asp:Image ID="product_imageLabel" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="300px"
                            ImageUrl='<%# "data:Image/png;base64,"
                                + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("product_image")) %>'/>
                         </div> 
                            <div style="margin-top:-300px;margin-left:310px;padding:10px"> 
                            <asp:Label ID="product_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("product_name") %>' Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <br/>
                            <asp:Label ID="product_compositionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("product_composition") %>' Font-Size="Larger"/>
                            <br/>
                            <asp:Label ID="brand_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "Brand Name : "+Eval("brand_name") %>' Font-Size="Larger" />
                            <br/>
                            <asp:Label ID="product_stock_unitLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("product_stock_unit")+" of "+Eval("product_quantity")+" "+Eval("product_quantity_unit") %>' Font-Size="Larger"/>
                            <br/>
                            <asp:Label ID="product_priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "MRP ₹ "+Eval("product_price") %>' ForeColor="#0E8CE4" Font-Size="Larger" />
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                             <asp:Label ID="Label_product_code" runat="server" Text='<%# "Product Code : "+Eval("product_code") %>' Font-Size="Larger"/>                                  
                             <br/>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button_addtocart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" CssClass="btn third"  CommandName="addtocart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("product_code")%>' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:DataList>
```

Here is the code of c# against OnItemCommand handler

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "addtocart")
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "randomtext", "not_login()", true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

`onclick = "DataList1_ItemCommand"`

in your HTML button code

because `onclick` Event Main Tips. The `"onclick"` event occurs when the user clicks on an element. It runs a specified line of code when you click an HTML object that has the “onclick” attribute. The event can be triggered by "object.onclick" or "object.addEventListener".